# Is it possible to create a IAM policy to restrict access to SSM parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Can someone please help me to create a IAM policy for below scenario if its possible to restrict access to SSM parameter store path from EC2 instance.

1. EC2 instance created and attached IAM role
2. Created 2 Assumed roles - `read & write` and `read-only`. Whoever has access to these roles, they can access to EC2 instance through "SSM session manager" using their SSO. e.g. session id/username looks like `m*@xyz.com` if I look at session manager history. That means first login to console using their assumed roles and connecting to ec2 instance through ssm.

Now I want store some parameters info by creating them in the parameter store and they should be accessible during maintenance activities on EC2 instance through attached IAM role.

Now I want to create an IAM policy and attached that EC2 IAM role to not access by anyone of `read&write` and `read-only` role members whose usernames starts with `m*@xyz.com`.

I tried creating a policy but it didn't work because by default it will be taking EC2 IAM user (EC2 IAM role) as assumed role even though session id shows individual.

I checked these details using below command to see what IAM user it is using to make API calls.

```
aws sts get-caller-identity

{
   "UserId": "ARNVDDGUSKDGKDGDKDGD:<ec2 instance id>",
   "Account": "aws account",
   "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::<aws account>:assumed-role/<ec2 instance iam role>/<ec2_instance_id>"
}
```

The output looks good and it is expecting in my case.

But How should I restrict access to SSM parameter store for the `read&write` and `read-only` users as mentioned above if they login to ec2 instance through ssm?

I've used below condition keys but no luck.

```
aws:username
arn:aws:sts::awsaccount:federated-user/m*@xyx.com
```

I am not sure If we can restrict because once user authorized to access EC2 then EC2 IAM permissions are applying as I understood.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.